# How can I perform 2FA using SMS for Firebase via the REST api?

Tags: android, rest, firebase, https, firebase-authentication

I'm writing an App with SDK restrictions. I have to make my own REST API calls and handle the responses myself. I can use Firebase authentication, and can setup email/password login with REST, but I need to perform 2FA via mobile phone numbers to complete the process.

Normally, the Firebase SDK handles this easily, but I need to do this via a REST API only. The [Firebase doco](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-api-usage) shows me how to perform email/password via REST, and a bunch of other related Authentication calls, but can I perform 2FA with mobile phone numbers using REST ? If so, can someone point to the documentation or provide a sample call/response ?

If it's not supported, would minting my own SMS verification via a cloud function be an acceptable alternative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, it isn't natively supported. Here's what you could do if you require the user to have 2FA before taking actions:

1. You set the up the security rules to require a certain property on a custom claims token.
2. Let the user sign in with a standard username and password on the client.
3. Get the token on the client
4. Send the token to a firebase function via a HTTP request
5. Verify the token in the firebase function
6. If the token is valid and has a uid property, make a request to twilio authy/do your 2FA logic here.

These instructions are incomplete, since authy has its own nuances you'll have to complete. But that's the gist of it.

These resources may be helpful:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens
https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/tutorials/two-factor-authentication-node-express

**Note:** You can probably spin your own 2FA solution by storing a temporary code in your firebase database and then sending a text message via Twilio using their SMS API.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using a 3rd party service for 2FA called via a cloudfunction, and then execute HTTP sign-in/"account creation" to Firebase after that. This ensures that users are verified before creating a session from login/new account. Not perfect but acceptable for my purposes.